# Test Method failing on account query

Tags: unit-test, account

I have created a class-which consists of a query to account which I need to test, if it is working correctly. So I have created a test class.

```
public class JSONSerialize {

        public void serializeAndDeserializeMethod(){
            Account acc = [select Id,Name from Account limit 1];
            String JSONStringAcc = JSON.serialize(acc);
            System.debug('******JSONStringAcc*******'+JSONStringAcc);
            List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSONStringAcc, List<Account>.class);
            System.debug('******accountList*******'+accountList );

        }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
public class JSONSerialize_Test {
    static testMethod void serializeAndDeserializeMethodTest(){
        JSONSerialize obj = new JSONSerialize();
        obj.serializeAndDeserializeMethod();
    }
}
```

However the test method is failing and it is showing-No rows returned.

I have test accounts in my org. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: You are serializing an object `String JSONStringAcc = JSON.serialize(acc);` and expecting a List of Object `List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSONStringAcc, List<Account>.class);` this is not fair.

Comment: Well my testclass is failing on the account query. Even if I remove the above lines, it is still throwing an error.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No rows returned in query

Comment: Are you sure you have at least an Account in your Org?

Comment: Probably not, I tried the code in my org, it passes with no problem (just replaced `Account acc` by `List<Account> acc`

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO the code is fine except the single to multiple conversion.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes, that's why I replaced single by multiple : Account by List<Account>

Comment: You really should complete the [Apex Testing Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) module to understand how to write effective unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to use your actual data for tests (especially if you don't have some). Instead you should remove the `seealldata` flag and

```
@isTest
public class JSONSerialize_Test {
static testMethod void serializeAndDeserializeMethodTest(){
    Test.startTest();
    insert new Account(Name="testAcct");
    JSONSerialize obj = new JSONSerialize();
    obj.serializeAndDeserializeMethod();
    Test.stopTest();
}}
```

Also the a test method should test something but it's probably the next step ;-)